# SSAS Dimension Attribute based on a SSAS calculated measure

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

I'm currently struggle with an issue and I hope you help with that.

I need to dynamically associate an attribute of a dimension in my SSAS cube (multidimensional) based on a calculation performed on the cube itself.

Simplifing, based on a date selected by the user, I have a calculation (already done) that returns the number of days that type of material is in stock. With that value I want to return an attribute based on a range of values.

for example:

```
Nr_Days_Calculated = 80
```

DIMENSION:

```
ID  INI  END        DSC

1     0  90         TextA

2    91  180        TextB

3   181  99999      TextC
```

Result : `1 - TextA`

Can anyone please help me? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable if your dimension also has dynamic calculations. Let me show you another example, but idea is the same.

I have a dimension [Repeat Customers], if a customer (identified by email) signed in the second, third, fourth time - move this customer to appropriate member of this dimension.

First, create dimension with one default member.

Second, add several empty members:

(you can skip it, because dim members are materialized in your case)

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[One] as NULL;      
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Two] as NULL;      
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Three] as NULL;      
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Four] as NULL;      
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Five] as NULL;      
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[6+] as NULL;      
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[N/A] as NULL;
```

Third, add their calculations:

```
SCOPE([Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[One],[Measures].[Count]);      
THIS=Count(Filter([Email].[Email].Members,([Measures].[Count],[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].&[0])=1));      
END SCOPE;      

SCOPE([Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Two],[Measures].[Count]);      
THIS=Count(Filter([Email].[Email].Members,([Measures].[Count],[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].&[0])=2));      
END SCOPE;      

...     

SCOPE([Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[6+],[Measures].[Count]);      
THIS=Count(Filter([Email].[Email].Members,([Measures].[Count],[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].&[0])>=6));      
END SCOPE;

SCOPE([Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[N/A],[Measures].[Count]);      
THIS=([Measures].[Count],[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].&[0])
-SUM({
 [Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[One]
,[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Two]
,[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Three]
,[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Four]
,[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[Five]
,[Repeat Customers].[Repeat Customers].[All].[6+]
},[Measures].[Count]);      
END SCOPE;
```

Output:

[image: DynamicDim]

I think your filter has to use >= and <= Nr_Days_Calculated. But not sure which measure are you trying to show. Is `1 - TextA` related to `[Measures].[Nr_Days_Calculated]`? If yes, we are good, just use your measure and SUM or else as aggregate instead of Count() in my case.

This is not the best performance solution (because of dynamic calculation), but still it works. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Alex Peshik it seems that this will help me... I will try to implement and them give feedback. To clarify, the output 1 - TextA is the ID and DSC in the dimension

Comment: yes, I understand. But which measure are you expecting to see distributed by this dimension? Should be smth like `COUNT OF ROWS where Nr_Days_Calculated = 80 falls to '1 - TextA' member`. It was simple in my case, because it was only count. Let's wait what you'll implement.

Comment: Basically I need to dynamically associate an attribute of the dimension based on the `Nr_Days_Calculated`. The idea is to have be able to use this dimension as an analysis entry point to the metric group.